# Cronjob to run hourly

Tags: linux, cron

I have written a small bash script which clears the logs (say that script name is clearLogs.sh).

- **My task:** To run the bash script on an hourly basis to clear the logs
- **What I have done so far:** I have created a symbolic link of my bash script and placed it in /etc/cron.hourly.

  ```
  example -> cd /etc/cron.hourly    
  ln -s /home/sam/clearLogs.sh  clearLogs.sh
  ```

Now, an hour has passed but the logs have not been deleted. If I run a script standalone it works as expected. Can you guys please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: To narrow down my question , I am wondering if creating a symbolic link in cron.hourly directory is a feasible solution?

Comment: Do you have `01 * * * *       root  /bin/run-parts /etc/cron.hourly` in `/etc/cron.d/crontab` ? Or sth similar maybe? Show contents of `/etc/cron.d/crontab`

Comment: What are the permissions of `/home/sam/clearLogs.sh`?

Comment: @h4bo, I havn't done anything on crontab , I thought by creating the symbolic  link of the script inside cron.hourly will serve the purpose

Comment: @John, permission is 777

Comment: @samantha it will, but only if you have properly configured crontab file - the line I pasted tells crontab to run scripts from /etc/cron.hourly each hour

Comment: Hi guys, For some strang e reason it doesnt work for few housr but after rebooting the system it is working. Thanks every one for the help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.in clearLogs.sh  add line: RUN_PATH=/you/script/path cd $RUN_PATH

2.cat "* */1 * * * /you/script/path/clearLogs.sh" >> $HOME/crontab.txt

3.crontab $HOME/crontab.txt

4.crontab -l,look all crontab job

Comment: I guess, the item 2 should be `echo`, not `cat`.